# HTTping in python

Tags: python

So my python program needs to be able to ping a website to see if it is up or not, i have made the ping program and then found out that this site only works with httping, after doing some googling about it i found almost nothing on the subject. Has anybody httping in python before? if so how did you do it?, Thanks for the help.
Here is my code for the normal ping (which works but not for the site i need it to work for)

```
 import os
 hostname = "sitename"
 response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
 if response == 0:
    print "good"
 else:
    print "bad"
```

Comment: ping is not part of the http protocol (it is in fact IMCP), what do you mean? You need to check if a website is available? Do you need a specific response? Please add some more information

Comment: [httping](https://github.com/flok99/httping) is simply sending an HTTP request and measures the time it takes. In Python, you can do that with requests and its [elapsed](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=elapsed#requests.Response.elapsed) parameter.

Comment: Some sites dont support the normal ping (which the site i need does not) but after some research i found away for something called httping which i got to work in the linux command line. just type in "sudo apt-get install httping" and you will see lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make a [HTTP HEAD request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

```
import requests

response = requests.head("http://www.example.com/")
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.elapsed)
else:
    print("did not return 200 OK")
```

Output:

```
0:00:00.238418
```

Answer (score 2):

To check accessibility of HTTP server you can make a GET request to the URL, which is as easy as:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/foo/bar")
print response.getcode()
```